# Add UIButton Icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, icons

[image http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/8529/uibutton.png](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/8529/uibutton.png)

I would like to implement something as shown on the picture. It would bring up a pickerView when it's tapped and write the chosen value onto it.

UIButton or TableViewCell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this and you will have to use the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style of `UITableViewCell` to have a `detailTextLabel`

1. You can set

   ```
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Pick a date & time";
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
   ```

   Now in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` , upon touch you can modally show a `uipickerView`.
2. You can use  `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryTypeDisclosureIndicator;`
    and add a textField as a subview to the `cell.contentView` and set

   ```
   textField.placeholder = @"Pick a date & time";
   textField.inputView = myPickerView;
   ```

Comment: Yes, this is how you have to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Create a button and put a label on it.Whenever picker value changed, change the text of label.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```